# how fix transform-style: preserve-3d on FireFox?

Tags: css

I have slider + cubes 3d and its cube have animation.
on chrome - very good works, but when see on firefox - cube transform on 2d image)
firefox - new version writes that it is supported =  transform-style: preserve-3, but this is probably wrong or something is missing ...

https://codepen.io/pen/?template=pozPYON

```
<div class="carousel-cube" data-backimage data-padimage="100">
  <figure>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="cub">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
            <img class="size1" src="/tmp/img3/1.png" alt="Дизайн1">
            <img class="size2" src="/tmp/img3/2.png" alt="Дизайн2">
            <img class="size3" src="/tmp/img3/3.png" alt="Дизайн3">
            <img class="size4" src="/tmp/img3/4.png" alt="Дизайн4">
            <img class="size5" src="/tmp/img3/5.png" alt="Дизайн5">
            <img class="size6" src="/tmp/img3/6.png" alt="Дизайн6">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<div class="item">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="cub">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
            <img class="size1" src="/tmp/img3/1.png" alt="Дизайн1">
            <img class="size2" src="/tmp/img3/2.png" alt="Дизайн2">
            <img class="size3" src="/tmp/img3/3.png" alt="Дизайн3">
            <img class="size4" src="/tmp/img3/4.png" alt="Дизайн4">
            <img class="size5" src="/tmp/img3/5.png" alt="Дизайн5">
            <img class="size6" src="/tmp/img3/6.png" alt="Дизайн6">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="cub">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
            <img class="size1" src="/tmp/img3/1.png" alt="Дизайн1">
            <img class="size2" src="/tmp/img3/2.png" alt="Дизайн2">
            <img class="size3" src="/tmp/img3/3.png" alt="Дизайн3">
            <img class="size4" src="/tmp/img3/4.png" alt="Дизайн4">
            <img class="size5" src="/tmp/img3/5.png" alt="Дизайн5">
            <img class="size6" src="/tmp/img3/6.png" alt="Дизайн6">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="cub">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
            <img class="size1" src="/tmp/img3/1.png" alt="Дизайн1">
            <img class="size2" src="/tmp/img3/2.png" alt="Дизайн2">
            <img class="size3" src="/tmp/img3/3.png" alt="Дизайн3">
            <img class="size4" src="/tmp/img3/4.png" alt="Дизайн4">
            <img class="size5" src="/tmp/img3/5.png" alt="Дизайн5">
            <img class="size6" src="/tmp/img3/6.png" alt="Дизайн6">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="cub">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
            <img class="size1" src="/tmp/img3/1.png" alt="Дизайн1">
            <img class="size2" src="/tmp/img3/2.png" alt="Дизайн2">
            <img class="size3" src="/tmp/img3/3.png" alt="Дизайн3">
            <img class="size4" src="/tmp/img3/4.png" alt="Дизайн4">
            <img class="size5" src="/tmp/img3/5.png" alt="Дизайн5">
            <img class="size6" src="/tmp/img3/6.png" alt="Дизайн6">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="cub">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
            <img class="size1" src="/tmp/img3/1.png" alt="Дизайн1">
            <img class="size2" src="/tmp/img3/2.png" alt="Дизайн2">
            <img class="size3" src="/tmp/img3/3.png" alt="Дизайн3">
            <img class="size4" src="/tmp/img3/4.png" alt="Дизайн4">
            <img class="size5" src="/tmp/img3/5.png" alt="Дизайн5">
            <img class="size6" src="/tmp/img3/6.png" alt="Дизайн6">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="cub">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
            <img class="size1" src="/tmp/img3/1.png" alt="Дизайн1">
            <img class="size2" src="/tmp/img3/2.png" alt="Дизайн2">
            <img class="size3" src="/tmp/img3/3.png" alt="Дизайн3">
            <img class="size4" src="/tmp/img3/4.png" alt="Дизайн4">
            <img class="size5" src="/tmp/img3/5.png" alt="Дизайн5">
            <img class="size6" src="/tmp/img3/6.png" alt="Дизайн6">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 
  </figure>
  <nav class="hidden">
    <button class="nav prev"> <- </button>
        <button class="nav next"> -> </button>
  </nav>
</div>
```